# How to detect change in specific column in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table structure like this :

subscribers with attributes:
id,
status

I want to have a way to check for the column status :
If the status change to 'unsubscribed' then i want to auto detect thats change and apply do something with that.

The workflow is like this :

Anywhere in the code call $subscriber->status = 'unsubscribed';
I want to detect that and do something with that.

Thanks for reading.

I had use isDirty of laravel but that had to write after every $subscriber->status = 'unsubscribed'; so its did not do the work.

Comment: Detect it to your controller so that you do not have to check `$subscriber->status = 'unsubscribed'` again and again. If query returns true do another operation and then pass it to the view

Comment: Try to share some of your code so that it will be easy to explain

Comment: why not you use 'isDirty' before saving your '$subscriber' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code to your model:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::updated(function (Subscriber $subscriber) {
        if ($subscriber->wasChanged('status')) {
            // Execute your code
        }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an Observer.

Comment: Thanks. This's what i want to achive. But the wasChanged method is for which laravel version? I'm currenly use 5.8 laravel.

Comment: I'm not sure. But in Laravel 5.8 you can use isDirty('status') instead

Comment: Looking at docs I believe you're still able to do this in Laravel 9: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that

```
const pagination = computed(() => {
    const item = {} as IPaginationAnt;
    item.total = option.value.pagination.totalElements;
    item.current = option.value.pagination.number;
    item.pageSize = option.value.pagination.size;
    return item;
  });
```

Comment: Is that helpful?